# Does the Ninth Legion Style contradict itself?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

The Ninth Legion Style provides benefits to a setup, wherein

- one hand there is a pick or spear,
- the other hand, there is a shield.

[image]

The Lesser Style is sound with this approach.

However, the Greater Style Associates Powers where the requirement is one empty hand. (I assume no shield in this case).

[image]

[image]

Is this contradicting or is there a trick that can solve the empty-hand problem? What I was thinking is to drop the shield as a Free Action, make the attack, and then an enchanted shield may be teleported back to hand as a Free Action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes, they contradict each other, though less so if you use a light shield.

From the Rules Compendium, p267:

> **Using a Shield**
> To use a shield, a creature must strap it to the forearm. Doing so is a standard action, unless otherwise noted. Removing a shield is also a standard action.

> **Light Shield**
> While using a light shield, a creature can use its shield hand for other purposes, such as holding another item or climbing, but the creature can't make attacks with that hand or with anything it is holding in that hand.

> **Heavy Shield**
> While using a heavy shield, a creature can't use its shield hand for any other task, since it must use that hand to handle the shield.

Note that if you wield a light shield, that hand is considered free but cannot be used to make attacks. Thus you could use Shifting Blade, but not Bludgeoning Vise, with a light shield. (Although Bludgeoning Vise doesn't say you have to use the free hand for the unarmed attack, just that you have to have a free hand; note to self, further investigation required).

A character wielding a spear/pick and a heavy shield gives up the ability to use the greater style powers on a Combat Challenge attack (assuming they all require a free hand). A character wielding a spear/pick and leaving their other hand free gives up the ability to use the lesser style powers on an opportunity attack. A character wielding a spear/pick and a light shield gives up the ability to use *some* of the greater style powers on a Combat Challenge attack.

Why did the authors describe the style as being based on using heavy shields then? Poor editing would be my guess.

Note that your plan to drop the shield will probably not work unless you have a magic shield that explicitly allows you to do so; the rules point out that the shield is strapped to your arm, not simply held, and requires a standard action to equip/stow (compared to a minor action to draw/sheathe a weapon).

#### Alternative Interpretation: Specific Beats General

It's possible to interpret things such that it works fine even with a heavy shield, however. Part of 4e is that specific rules trump general rules when there's a contradiction. *In general* the powers listed by the Ninth Legion Shield feat require a free hand. However, the Ninth Legion Shield says that in the specific case when you are wielding a one-handed pick or spear *and* making a Combat Challenge attack, you can use those powers.

This could be read as overriding the free hand restriction of those powers, though the fact that it neither explicitly says so nor specifically requires you to wield a shield makes me dubious; that same logic could be used to say that it allows you to use those encounter powers even if you're already expended them during the encounter, or even if you don't actually know those powers!